# Pass textbox from a page to Custom usercontrol using dependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have a Custom user control in a silver light Project.

I use it in other page and want to Pass textbox to Custom User control.

For this I create dependcy as below :

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxControl", typeof(TextBox), typeof(SpellCheck), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    public TextBox TextBoxControl
    {
        get { return (TextBox)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
            TextSpell = value;
        }
    }
```

Here TextSpell is a textbox.

And I use this property in a silver light page as below:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtNote" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400"/>
<myButton:SpellCheck x:Name="btnSpell" Grid.Row="3" TextBoxControl="txtNote"  Grid.Column="1" Width="20" Height="20"  Margin="403,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

But I give s me a error : "The Typeconvertor for Texbox dose not support converting from a string"

So How can I pass a text box in custom usercontrol.

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not simply use the field name (`x:Name`) string of the TextBox as a value for your `TextBoxControl` property. Instead you may use an `ElementName` binding like this:

```
<myButton:SpellCheck TextBoxControl="{Binding ElementName=txtNote}" ... />
```

---

And there are more things wrong:

- In the CLR wrappers of a dependency property, you should never call anything else than `GetValue` and `SetValue`. The explanation is given in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) article on MSDN. Instead, you have to have a `PropertyChangedCallback` registered with the property metadata.
- There is a naming convention for the static dependency property fields. They should be named like the property, with a trailing *Property*.
- The default value has to match the property type. Your `false` value is not valid, and might be `null` instead. But as that is the default anyway, you should leave it out completely.

The declaration would now look like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxControlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "TextBoxControl", typeof(TextBox), typeof(SpellCheck),
        new PropertyMetadata(TextBoxControlPropertyChanged));

public TextBox TextBoxControl
{
    get { return (TextBox)GetValue(TextBoxControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextBoxControlProperty, value); }
}

private static void TextBoxControlPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var spellCheck = (SpellCheck)obj;
    spellCheck.TextSpell = (TextBox)e.NewValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Clemens Thanks for your reply but I can not access Value in TextBoxControlPropertyChanged event so it gives error in  spellCheck.TextSpell = value.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy and paste error from your code sample. See my edit please.